# Laravel Route Facade not found on live server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I uploaded my Laravel installation to a live server and I'm getting the following error.

[image]

Or you can see it live here: http://atriumglaskunst.uniweb.be/

> The PHP installation is at 5.6.17 and the .env file is also included on the server. I've never seen this error before. I don't have SSH access to the server at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

Comment: I'm affraid I don't have SSH access at the moment, I'll add it to my question. Thank you.